# Should I use Wordpress Transient API in this case?

Tags: wordpress, caching

I'm writing a simple Wordpress plugin for work and am wondering if using the Transients API is practical in this case, or if I should seek out another way.

The plugin's purpose is simple. I'm making a call to USZip Web Service (http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?op=GetInfoByZIP) to retrieve data. Our sales team is using a Lead Intake sheet that the plugin will run on.

I wanted to reduce the number of API calls, so I thought of setting a transient for each zip code as the key and store the incoming data (city and zip). If the corresponding data for a given zip code already exists, then no need to make an API call.

Here are my concerns:
1.  After a quick search, I realized that the transient data is stored in the wp_options table and storing the data would balloon that table in no time. Would this cause a significance performance issue if the db becomes huge?
2.  Is this horrible practice to create this many transient keys? It could easily becomes thousands in a few months time.

If using Transient is not the best way, could you please help point me in the right direction? Thanks!

P.S.  I opted for the Transients API vs the Options API. I know zip codes don't change often, but they sometimes so. I set expiration time of 3 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A less-inflated solution would be:

1. Store a single option called `uszip` with a serialized array inside the option
2. Grab the entire array each time and simply check if the zip code exists
3. If it doesn't exist, grab the data and save the whole transient again

You should make sure you don't hit the upper bounds of a serialized array in this table (9,000 elements) considering 43,000 zip codes exist in the US. However, you will most likely have a very localized subset of zip codes.

Comment: That's a great idea, thank you.  I believe that we will be hitting those limits eventually so to build on your idea, I think I'll create several numbered options (0-9) and call them depending on the first digit of zipcode.